# Serialized Entities displaying only ID

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm using JMSSerializer and FOSRestBundle. I have a fairly typical object graph, including some recursion.

What I would like to accomplish is that included objects beyond a certain depth or in general are listed only with their ID, but when serialized directly, with all data.

So, for example:
Users => Groups => Users

when requesting /user/1 the result should be something like

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "groups": [ { "id": 10 }, { "id": 11 } ] }
```

While when I request /group/10 it would be:

```
{ "id": 10, "name": "Groupies", "users": [ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 2 }, { "id": 4 } ] }
```

With @MaxDeph I can hide the included arrays completely, so I get
    { "id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "groups": [] }

But I would like to include just the IDs so that the REST client can fetch them if it needs them, or consult his cache, or do whatever.

I know I can manually cobble this together using groups, but for consistency reasons I was wondering if I can somehow enable this behaviour in my entire application, maybe even with a reference to maxdepth so I can control where to include IDs and where to include full objects?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of those finding this:

I found no other solution, but doing this with groups works just fine and gives me the result I was looking for.